# Android WebView - NTLM Authentication

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a WebView embedded in my application. I am trying to view a webpage that uses NTLM authentication. How can I perform the NTLM authentication using the WebView and view this page?

I was successfully able to authenticate to this page using DefaultHttpClient and the JCIFS Library. But how can I do it for the WebView?

Answer (score 1):

It has been two years since I asked this question. In the meantime, I figured out the answer to this question -

WebView supports NTLM authentication out-of-the-box. The `onReceivedHttpAuthRequest` callback in `WebViewClient` has a method parameter a method parameter named `handler`. This is of the type `HttpAuthHandler`. `handler.proceed(username, password)` will automatically authenticate to the web server using NTLM protocol. This handler abstracts the authentication protocol used. Both Basic and NTLM authentication work using the same line of code.

Comment: How to download a ntlm proteted file. Ever encountered about these type of requirement ?

Comment: You can use Apache HTTPClient to download files that require NTLM authentication. Apache HTTPClient supports NTLM authentication since 4.2.3. You can use the latest version. Reference - https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/ntlm.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem! There is another indirect way. You get the `HttpResponse` and then save the html file to the internal storage and then load the file into the `WebView`. I never tried this before, though.